# Is there a way to get MySQL 5.7/MariaDB to return 0 or 1 for rows that exist in a where IN() query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a way to get MySQL 5.7/MariaDB to return 0 or 1 for rows that exist in a where `IN()` query?

like maybe SUM/IF/complex subquery SQL trickery? It could be the id or just a simple 1/0 to know which exists or not.

I thought if I could just add `IFNULL(id,0)` to a empty row it would return 4 results with 0, but it only shows 3:

Imagine a simple id table:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EXAMPLE QUERY:

```
SELECT IFNULL(id,0) FROM tbl WHERE id in (1,2,3,4);
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  0 |
------

4 results
```

ACTUAL

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+

3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
--------
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to return both the existing id and empty ids and not use [temporary] tables, it could be a complex subquery using `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET` or combination of where `IN()` and `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, etc, etceven a stored procedure, or possibly JSON trickery, etc.

Comment: Tell us something about you IN values.  How many will there be?  Are they in a limited range of values?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: You can't get 4 rows from a 3-row table.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IN` criteria needs to exist as rows for the result to be rows. So:

```
SELECT coalesce(id, 0)
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS e
   UNION SELECT 2
   UNION SELECT 3
   UNION SELECT 4) t2
LEFT JOIN tbl ON id=e
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e4695ad8031cd5a5c8dec57c5f54519)

If its always a sequence, mariadb's in-build [sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/) creates magic tables of sequences:

```
SELECT coalesce(id, 0)
FROM seq_1_to_4 t2
LEFT JOIN tbl ON id=seq
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ef08c32ac7ac978e9d2e883704fa9d32)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but your example only shows 1 result, I'm looking for 4 results when only 3 ids are in the table, I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: ack. clarified answer accordingly.

Comment: Where is the id IN() part? it looks like your SELECT 2, SELECT 3, etc. are hardcoded

Comment: yes, that's the new "IN" as your arbitrary list. Alternately `create temporary table tbl2 (e INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY); insert ... ; select .. FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl ON ...`

Comment: @user13611099 if you want a result against each item in left or right operand then it must be in a join not in IN() operator

Comment: I will accept your answer later if no one else posts with SUM/IF/IN trickery that 
(doesn't use tables) that I'm looking for, apparently what I'm trying to do is a lot
harder than I thought..but still being hopeful, so by the end of the day or so if no one else comes up with a better answer, since you were first I will mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are actually all some other table, select from that and left join tbl.  If not, emulate such a table:

```
select in_ids.id, tbl.id is not null as id_exists
from (select 0 id union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) in_ids
left join tbl on tbl.id=in_ids.id
```

If there is some rule (all integers in a range, for instance) in MySQL 8 or mariadb 10.2, you would use a recursive common table expression instead:

```
with recursive in_ids as (
    select 1 as id
    union all
    select id+1 from in_ids
    where id < 4
)
select in_ids.id, tbl.id is not null as id_exists
from in_ids
left join tbl on tbl.id=in_ids.id
```

You can also generate a sequence large enough to cover your possible range and then keep your IN to only look at particular values (here, from 1 to 1024):

```
select sequence.n, tbl.id is not null as id_exists
from (
    select 1+i+4*(j+4*(k+4*(l+4*m))) n
    from (select 0 i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) i
    cross join (select 0 j union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) j
    cross join (select 0 k union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) k
    cross join (select 0 l union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) l
    cross join (select 0 m union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) m
) sequence
left join tbl on tbl.id=sequence.n
where sequence.n in (1,2,3,4);
```

or with CTEs:

```
with recursive sequence as (
    select 1 as n
    union all
    select n+1 from sequence
    where n < 1024
)
left join tbl on tbl.id=sequence.n
where sequence.n in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: The ids would be from IN() dynamically not from a table

Comment: Then you dynamically form the list of unions instead.

Comment: added more suggestions; it would be helpful to know more about the values in your IN

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives, but it is random id's that are not sequential so most of those examples would not work..it appears there is no easy way to do it and I think cross join/union all would degrade performance. I appreciate your efforts but starting to think this is a lost cause and no easy way to do it.

Comment: even if they are random, are they in a specific range?   I wouldn't assume the performance is bad without actually trying for your actual case